# Powershell variable doesn't contain all the objects

Tags: arrays, powershell, variables, foreach

I got the following variable **$listofusers** which returns the below objects in two columns:

```
SourceUser                         DestinationUser
----------                         ---------------
username1@legacy.company.corp username1@modern.company.corp
username2@legacy.company.corp username2@modern.company.corp
username3@legacy.company.corp username3@modern.company.corp
username4@legacy.company.corp username4@modern.company.corp
```

I now need to process this list of users in a foreach loop. I have tried so far the following but without luck yet:

```
$Results = ForEach ($User in $listofusers) {
    Write-Host "Processing SourceUser $($User.SourceUser)"
    Write-Host "Processing DestinationUser $($User.DestinationUser)"

    #Assign the content to variables
    $SourceUsers = $User.SourceUser
    $DestinationUsers = $User.DestinationUser

}
```

It only returns me the last line of the objects:

```
$SourceUsers
RETURN ONLY: username4@legacy.company.corp

$DestinationUsers
RETURN ONLY: username4@modern.company.corp
```

How can I add all the objects in the variable **$listofusers** for further processing?

UPDATE:

I am trying to achieve the following that's why I have broken the association in **listofusers**

```
$SourceUser = @()
$DestinationUser = @()
$Results = ForEach ($User in $listofusers)
{
    Write-Host "Processing SourceUser $($User.SourceUser)"
    Write-Host "Processing DestinationUser $($User.DestinationUser)"

    #Assign the content to variables
    $SourceUser += $User.SourceUser
    $DestinationUser += $User.DestinationUser

    #Cannot get that variables working yet
    $sourceusername, $sourcedomain = $SourceUser -split ("@")
    $DestinationUsername, $destinationDomain = $DestinationUser -split ("@")
    $SourceAccount = Get-ADUser $sourceusername -server $sourcedomain -Properties objectSid
    $TargetAccount = Get-ADUser $DestinationUsername -Server $destinationDomain   
}
```

Is there any better way to achieve that and get those variables to that point?

**NEW UPDATE:**

The purpose of the script would be to achieve the following cmdlets for processing ad objects:

```
    #get the objectSid of the source account
    $objectSid = $SourceAccount.objectSid

    #copy source account objectSid to target account msExchMasterAccountSid
    $TargetAccount | Set-ADUser -Replace @{"msExchMasterAccountSid"=$objectSid}
    #enable targetaccount
    $TargetAccount | Enable-ADAccount

    #disable the source account
    $SourceAccount | Disable-ADAccount
    #move the migrated user into prod OU
    $TargetAccount | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "ou=test,dc=contoso,dc=com"
```

Thanks

Comment: i dont undertand, `$listOfUsers` already is a collection...

Comment: I just wanted to split the columns in the variable keeping the logic for further processing. I think Itchydon gave me the right input.

Comment: @StackLad - as `Roque Sosa` implied ... there is _rarely_ a good reason to break up the associated items as you are doing. they are already in a collection and can be easily used as is via the same method you are using to destroy the association ... `$listofusers.SourceUser` for the whole set, OR `$listofusers[$Index].SourceUser` [or iterate thru the list] to get just one. are you sure you need to break the association?

Comment: Hi @Lee_Dailey, I am not sure, to be honest, I need to progress this and see how it goes. In the meantime would be able to provide me with an example as per your consideration?

Comment: @StackLad - the Answers by `Itchydon` & `Roque Sosa` contain the reason for your problem AND a working way to break the association into two independent collections. there is nothing to give you as an example of NOT breaking the association since you have not mentioned the reasoning that got you to that point. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, I have edited my post with the missing info.

Comment: @StackLad - please check my Answer for one way to deal with the need for individual values while keeping the original association of the various parts.

Comment: Hi @Lee_Dailey, I like the approach on your logic and was wondering if you could help me to complete the missing parts I have added in the post shown as "NEW UPDATE". That would complete the script I am currently working on. Many thanks

Comment: @StackLad - OK, i rewrote my Answer with what will LIKELY work. as before, i cannot test it since i have no AD access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a demo of the concept i was trying to get across. [*grin*] it keeps the association of the objects in your CSV in the original object for as long as possible. the code has NOT been tested since i have no AD access.

what it does ...

- fakes reading in a CSV file
  when you are ready to use real data, replace the entire "region" with a call to `Import-CSV`.
- iterates thru the list
- builds a splat of the parameters for the AD calls
  see `Get-Help about_Splatting` for more info on that *wonderfully useful* idea.
- calls `Get-AdUser` with each to the Source/Target user data sets
- stores the above
- uses the stored account info to ...
  == replace the `.objectSid` of the Target account
  == enable the Target account
  == disable the Source account
  == Move the Target account to the desired OU
  the hard coded OU could be set with a variable to make this a tad more flexible. however, this seems to be a one-off operation - so there is likely no benefit.

if you want to add logging, do so in the same loop.

there is no error handling, either. that likely should be added with a `try/catch` around each AD call & logging of both success and failure.

the code ...

```
#region >>> fake reading in a CSV file
#    in real life, use Import-CSV
$UserList = @'
SourceUser, DestUser
ABravo@Old.com, ABravo@NewDomain.com
BCharlie@Old.com, BCharlie@NewDomain.com
CDelta@Old.com, CDelta@NewDomain.com
DEcho@Old.com, DEcho@NewDomain.com
EFoxtrot@Old.com, EFoxtrot@NewDomain.com
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv
#endregion >>> fake reading in a CSV file

ForEach ($UL_Item in $UserList)
    {
    Write-Host 'Processing ...'
    Write-Host ('    SourceUser {0}' -f $UL_Item.SourceUser)
    Write-Host ('    DestinationUser {0}' -f $UL_Item.DestUser)

    Write-Host '__ Source Account __'
    $GADU_Params_1 = [ordered]@{
        Identity = $UL_Item.SourceUser.Split('@')[0]
        Server = $UL_Item.SourceUser.Split('@')[1]
        Properties = 'objectSid'
        }
    $SourceAccount = Get-ADUser @GADU_Params_1

    Write-Host '__ Target Account __'
    $GADU_Params_2 = [ordered]@{
        Identity = $UL_Item.DestUser.Split('@')[0]
        Server = $UL_Item.DestUser.Split('@')[1]
        }
    $TargetAccount = Get-ADUser @GADU_Params_2

    Write-Host 'Making changes ...'
    # all these piped objects are slower than making _direct_ calls
    #    however, i don't have any way to test the code, so i can't use what likely is faster
    #    something like >>> 
    #    Set-AdUser -Identity $TargetAccount -Replace @{
    #        'msExchMasterAccountSid' = $objectSid
    #        }
    # note that i also replaced the unneeded _double_ quotes with the safer _single_ quotes
    $TargetAccount |
        Set-AdUser -Replace @{
        'msExchMasterAccountSid' = $SourceAccount.objectSid
        }
    $TargetAccount |
        Enable-AdAccount
    $SourceAccount |
        Disable-AdAccount
    $TargetAccount |
        Move-AdObject -TargetPath 'ou=test,dc=contoso,dc=com'

    Write-Host '=' * 30
    Write-Host ''
    }
```

no output shown since i can't actually run this AD stuff. [*grin*]

Comment: Thanks, Lee_Dailey this is very helpful for me to test and implement further.

Comment: @StackLad - you are very welcome! glad to help when i can ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

`$SourceUsers` and `$DestinationUsers` contain only the last ones becasue youa re replacing the value on each foreach iteration.

if you want it to separate the properties try this:

```
$SourceUsers = $User | select SourceUser -ExpandProperty SourceUser
$DestinationUsers = $User | select DestinationUser -ExpandProperty DestinationUser
```

That will create a collection of only those strings. you wont be able to access those values by property anymore, meaning that is a simple String[] after the `-ExpandProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$SourceUsers = @()
$DestinationUsers = @()
$Results = ForEach ($User in $listofusers) {
    Write-Host "Processing SourceUser $($User.SourceUser)"
    Write-Host "Processing DestinationUser $($User.DestinationUser)"

    #Assign the content to variables
    $SourceUsers += $User.SourceUser
    $DestinationUsers += $User.DestinationUser
}
```

- `$SourceUsers = @()` and `$DestinationUsers = @()` creates two empty
  arrays which we will use in the loop
- `+=` is an assignment operator which enables us to assign more than
  one value to a variable.  According to the documentation: *Increases
  the value of a variable by the specified value, or appends the
  specified value to the existing value.*

Comment: Yup - that was what I wanted to achieve for that and worked also in that way:

    #Assign the content to variables
    $SourceUsers = $listofusers.SourceUser
    $DestinationUsers = $listofusers.DestinationUser

Thanks for your help :-)